# Regex for removing all but the first number from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a javascript replace regex that will strip out everything but the first number in a string. (The last will also work as well, see my test cases below)

Given the following:

```
P1, PROTECTED 1
or
P3, PROTECTED 3
or
P10, PROTECTED 10
```

I need 1,3, or 10

I need to only return the first or last number. It'll be between 1 and 10. They're the same.

```
var foo = 'P10, PROTECTED 10';
foo.replace(/(\d+)/,'');
```

strips out the first number...I need the exact opposite

Comment: Search using `/^\D*(\d+).*/` and replace with `$1`

Comment: OP wants a `replace` not `match` here. There might be better dupe link but not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
^\D*(\d+).*
```

and replace with `'$1'` (capture group #1)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iREs5h/1)

**Code:**

```js
const arr = ['P1, PROTECTED 1',
'P3, PROTECTED 3',
'P10, PROTECTED 10'];

const re = /^\D*(\d+).*/m;

arr.forEach(el => console.log(el.replace(re, '$1')));
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `\D*`: Match 0 or more non-digits
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `.*`: Match everything till line end

Comment: foo= foo.replace(/^\D*(\d+).*/, '$1'); seems to have done it. thanks a lot!